# Flot graph shifting upwards when trying to hide the second axis ticks

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I am currently working on some flot graphs that display single and multiple sets of data relating to time. Below is an example image of a single set of data on the graph.

[Single data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdmYf.png)

A date time picker allows a user to compare two time ranges where the second data set draws over the initial set. The issue I'm having is that when the second dataset is drawn over the first the whole graph shifts upwards revealing a large white space where the hidden ticks should be, see the example image below.

[Multiple dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Broip.png)

As you can see the data sets are different time ranges therefore can't be on the same axis as they are a comparison. Here's my options for the axes.

```
xaxes: [{
            tickColor: "#fff",
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: timeFormat,
            minTickSize: tickSize,
            font: {
                style: "normal",
                color: "#666666"
            },
            axisLabel: xLabel,
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 11,
            axisLabelColour: "#666666",
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Open Sans',
            axisLabelPadding: 20
        },
        {
            ticks: [],
            mode: "time",
            timeFormat: timeFormat
        }],
```

applying the option show: false on the second xaxis removes the shifting completely however because it is false my tooltips for the graph points are also removed.

I m using flot.time, flot.tooltip and flot.axislabels if needed to know.
This is my first question so any feedback would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**My example on JSFiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/hnjz1nyn/2/)

It all comes down to 2 main changes. Assign your compare graph data to second x-axis:

```
var dataSet = [{
            data:  [
                [1467669600000, 12],
                [1467709200000, 14]
            ],
            label: 'data1',
            xaxis: 1
        }, {
            data:  [
                [1467583200000, 15],
                [1467622800000, 13],
                [1467662400000, 16]
            ],
            label: 'data2',
            xaxis: 2
        }];
```

For aesthetics, you should hide the second x-axis, so it won't mirror the same hours (set `show: false`)

```
{
    "show": false,
    "mode": "time",
    "timeformat": "%H:%M",
    "tickSize": [2, "hour"],
    "min": 1467583200000,
    "max": 1467666000000,
    "timezone": "browser"
}
```

Comment: I've edited your JSFiddle changing most of the options and now it works! i must have missed a setting in my initial code as i had originally tried the show: false option leading to my tooltip breaking. Anyway thank you very much.